# Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 RC - Crash when stop debugging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I updated to Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 RC since I want to be on-the-edge with the XAML Designer.

When I stop debugging or an exception occurs in a Windows Phone 8.1 App, I crash every time and my only solution is to restart visual studio..

My solution: For now I rollback-ed to Visual Studio 2015.

Anyone knows why?

Comment: Same issue here, Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 RC will crash simply upon loading a solution! A "NullReferenceException" is mentioned in the crash details.

Comment: similar problems here. 
crashes on some projects loading.
crashes on some projects debugging.
crashes in typescript

Comment: oh and I lost almost all code snippets

Comment: Martin, Erwin, Mikeon, can you guys help us narrow down causes of crashes? You can catch the crash by starting second instance of VS, then attaching to first one, and when debugger catches the crash, save the dump (from Debug menu > Save dump file...) and share it with me? I can take a look and see what crashes. Additionally, you can collect setup logs by running Collect.exe (see bottom of this page for instructions: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3039361), and sharing resulting CAB.

Comment: After I stopped my asp.net mvc once, it doesn't start it again and I have to restart VS. How do i roll back?

Answer (score 3):

I've figured that this crash happens when the solution contains a WPF project (which doesn't needs to be the start project or to be started at all) and the XAML UI debuggintools are enabled.
Going to tools -> options -> debugging and unchecking xaml ui debuggingtools stopped the crashes for me.

Comment: Suchiman, can you help us narrow down this crash? Can you collect the dump when VS crashes? Start second instance of VS, attach it to the first one, and then, when crash reproduces in the first one, it will break into second VS. In Debug menu, there is Save dump... command. Please share it using VS Feedback, and someone will take a look...

Comment: @SrdjanJovcic i tried today but VS didn't seem to crash after reenabling it, but at this point i'm also not certain anymore if this was with CTP 1 or already in RC 1. I will leave it enabled and keep an eye on it!